# ng-repeat showing only the last item?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I have a basic API call, which returns an object. I want to iterate through the object to show the Sessions Played per Champ, my code ise:

```
          for( var c = 0; c < json['champions'].length; c++) {
        data.sessP = json['champions'][c]['stats'].totalSessionsPlayed;
        console.log(json['champions'][c]['stats'].totalSessionsPlayed);
      }
```

In my page I have:

```
 <span ng-repeat="sessP in info.sessP">
    {{info.sessP}}
  </span>
```

Within the console, a list of about 6 or 7 totalSessionsPlayed is output correctly, so I know it is there, however on the page, only the last result of the output is displayed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v19nF.jpg

Am I doing something wrong? I would presume I'm accessing the object correctly, as a value is displayed on the page, just not all of them :(

Thanks

Comment: you should use `{{sessP}}` and get other things from that

Comment: what is info.sessP  ?

Comment: info is what Data is binded to before pushing it to the page. I'm using mustache as a Template engine. Info is essentially data.

Comment: I changed to:  <span ng-repeat="x in info">
    {{info.sessP}}
  </span>
Still displays just number 11? Why wont it repeat over each of the results? aaaah!

Comment: Why do you need mustache in an angular app? Or why would you even want to use it? Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

you should bind array like this...

```
$scope.sessP  = [];
for( var c = 0; c < json['champions'].length; c++) {
    $scope.sessP.push(json['champions'][c]['stats'].totalSessionsPlayed);
    console.log(json['champions'][c]['stats'].totalSessionsPlayed);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span ng-repeat="sesP in sessP">
    {{sesP}}
</span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately now nothing is displayed. Thanks for trying bud!